# What can be added to a non positive definite matrix to make it positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm reading about the Newton Algorithm for optimization, and when the hessian is not positive definite, it says that I can add a matrix $E_k$ such that $B_k = \nabla^2 f(x_k) + E_k$ is sufficiently positive definite. What does that mean? How does $E_k$ looks like?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of ways of constructing $E_{k}$.  One simple approach would to be to add a small positive multiple of the identity matrix, $\alpha I$, to $B_{k}$.  This shifts the eigenvalues of $B_{k}$ to the right by $\alpha$, which will ensure that the perturbed matrix is positive definite.

A variety of more sophisticated approaches that try to make $E_{k}$ as small as possible have been developed over the years.  These are typically incorporated into an algorithm that computes a Cholesky factorization of the perturbed matrix, dynamically adjusting the perturbation in response to the values encountered during the Cholesky factorization.

A recent master thesis on this topic is: [Thomas McSweeney.  Modified Cholesky Decomposition and Applications.  Manchester Institute of Mathematical Sciences, 2017.](http://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/2599/1/modified_cholesky_decomposition_and_applications.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reference! My covariance matrices are singular because of the process generating the data whose covariance I'm considering. It seems that adding an eps multiple of the identity would make my matrix positive definite and hence make Cholesky succeed. I guess the question is whether there's a simple way to choose eps, and then "subtract it" to correct the resulting matrix

Comment: No, there isn't a simple way to add $\epsilon$ and take it back later.