# Cholesky-like decomposition that works on singular matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a variant of Cholesky-like decomposition that works for singular matrices?

My problem is that all implementations of Cholesky I found fail when the matrix is singular in machine precision.

One idea for such decomposition is to consider duality between Cholesky and Gram-Schmidt. Once you encounter vectors that are linear combinations of previous vectors, skip them. This for instance produces the following decomposition for rank-3 matrix below.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 9 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
 0 & 2 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{9} & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{9}{4} & 1 \\
 0 & \frac{9}{4} & 1 \\
 0 & \frac{9}{4} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 9 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{8}{9} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{9} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{9}{4} & \frac{9}{4} & \frac{9}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-singular-ldl.nb)

Comment: Certainly, there are solutions. Your factorization is an LDLT factorization of the matrix $A$. It is an extension of Cholesky factorization that will not fail if a pivot is strictly negative. One could transform an SVD into the shape that you seek with row operations from the left and column operations from the right, but this is not necessarily a good idea. What do you really want to achieve, what is the application that has lead you to this question? This information is really necessary before a good answer can be given.

Comment: What I want is Cholesky (because it's cheap) that doesn't crash on singular matrices. Is there an algorithm that has the same cost as Cholesky, but works on matrices like in the example above?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You seem to have already found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2946084/81360), but you may find the $LDL^T$ algorithms from the linked thesis to be useful.

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, modified Cholesky seems like it would do the job. I keep seeing mentions that it's "expensive", but didn't try it, implementation seems hard to find

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Alternatively, I believe you should be able to combine a QR decomposition (about as cheap as Cholesky) with an $r \times r$ Cholesky factorization (where $r$ is the rank of your matrix) to get the desired result. I haven't found any literature on it; if that sounds like an appealing approach, I can write up an explanation as an answer later today.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yeah I realized after my initial statement that I was probably wrong QR being cheaper. So all together this method would be about 2.5 - 3.5 times more expensive (depending on how big the rank is compared to the matrix size) than the usual Cholesky approach; I'm not sure if that's an acceptable slow down in your context.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Regarding your idea for a decomposition: I believe determining which vectors are not linear combinations of previous columns (i.e. the "pivot columns" of the matrix) amounts to computing the matrix's row-echelon form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using $QR$ decomposition: the following results in a decomposition of the form $A = MM^T$ with $M$ of full rank of size $n \times r$ (with $r$ equal to the rank of $A$), but $M$ is not necessarily in lower-triangular form. If it is desired, $M$ can be put into lower-triangular form with a further $QR$ decomposition $M^T = QR$.

Begin with a (symmetric) positive semidefinite $n \times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $r<n$. An exact $QR$ decomposition $A = QR$ must have the form
$$
Q = \pmatrix{Q_1 & Q_2}, \quad R = \pmatrix{R_1\\ 0}
$$
where $Q$ is square of size $n$, $Q_1$ has $r$ columns and $R_1$ has $R$ rows. Thus, the columns of $Q_1$ form an orthonormal basis for the column-space of $A$.

It follows that $Q_1^TAQ_1$ is strictly positive definite. Moreover, we have $Q_2^TA = (AQ_2)^T = 0$. Compute a Cholesky decomposition $LL^T = Q_1^TAQ_1$. From there, we may deduce that
$$
\pmatrix{L \\0} \pmatrix{L\\0}^T = \pmatrix{LL^T & 0\\0 & 0} = \pmatrix{Q_1^TAQ_1 & Q_1^TAQ_2\\ Q_2^TAQ_1 & Q_2^TAQ_2} = Q^TAQ.
$$
Conclude that
$$
A = Q\pmatrix{L\\0}\pmatrix{L \\ 0}^TQ^T = \left[Q\pmatrix{L \\0} \right]\left[ Q\pmatrix{L \\0}\right]^T
$$